# How to pull a specific value from dynamic JSON dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array, json-deserialization

I'm trying to pull one specific piece of data from the json received from a geocoding request.
This is not a duplicate of the myriads of similar-sounding questions, because the json is dynamic and has extremely irregular arrays that change slightly between responses, so I can't create a model to parse to, neither can I navigate through it using key names.
This is the json of one response:

```
{  
   "Response":{  
      "MetaInfo":{  
         "Timestamp":"2019-07-28T13:23:04.898+0000"
      },
      "View":[  
         {  
            "_type":"SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId":0,
            "Result":[  
               {  
                  "Relevance":1.0,
                  "MatchLevel":"houseNumber",
                  "MatchQuality":{  
                     "City":1.0,
                     "Street":[  
                        0.9
                     ],
                     "HouseNumber":1.0
                  },
                  "MatchType":"pointAddress",
                  "Location":{  
                     "LocationId":"NT_Opil2LPZVRLZjlWNLJQuWB_0ITN",
                     "LocationType":"point",
                     "DisplayPosition":{  
                        "Latitude":41.88432,
                        "Longitude":-87.63877
                     },
                     "NavigationPosition":[  
                        {  
                           "Latitude":41.88449,
                           "Longitude":-87.63877
                        }
                     ],
                     "MapView":{  
                        "TopLeft":{  
                           "Latitude":41.8854442,
                           "Longitude":-87.64028
                        },
                        "BottomRight":{  
                           "Latitude":41.8831958,
                           "Longitude":-87.63726
                        }
                     },
                     "Address":{  
                        "Label":"425 W Randolph St, Chicago, IL 60606, United States",
                        "Country":"USA",
                        "State":"IL",
                        "County":"Cook",
                        "City":"Chicago",
                        "District":"West Loop",
                        "Street":"W Randolph St",
                        "HouseNumber":"425",
                        "PostalCode":"60606",
                        "AdditionalData":[  
                           {  
                              "value":"United States",
                              "key":"CountryName"
                           },
                           {  
                              "value":"Illinois",
                              "key":"StateName"
                           },
                           {  
                              "value":"Cook",
                              "key":"CountyName"
                           },
                           {  
                              "value":"N",
                              "key":"PostalCodeType"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get just the two coordinates inside NavigationPosition.

Before I start the tedious work of creating a method to manually pull out the data I need from the unparsed string, does anyone have a solution? Is there a way to iterate anonymously through the json arrays using a foreach or if statement?

Comment: xpath comes to mind.

Comment: path example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm - if this looks like something you want to try but can't figure out, i'll see about a full example for you. let me know.

Comment: In what was is the json dynamic? Surely there must be some sort of logical structure?

Comment: If the location can be anywhere, but is always with the same name, you could use `JsonTokenReader` to get it from the document since it goes through all the properties

Comment: If you really can't rely on key names(jsonpath), then your only option is to walk the object tree and check that current JsonObject is of the {Latitude, Longtitude} form. But it is extremely error-prone as there are at least two more properties with such signature in the sample, so I'd rather try to enforce a proper consistent schema on the service that provides such data...

Comment: Will `NavigationPosition` always be an *array of objects*? If so, you just want the first one or do you want the whole array?

Comment: Also, please specify **what you know**. For instance, will the name of the property always be `NavigationPosition`? Will it always be an array? Will the array always have an object with a property `Latitude` and one `Longitude`? **How dynamic is it?**

Comment: @andyb952 this is exactly how it comes, there is a structure but it's very irregular

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the individual objects are always the same, so NavigationPosition is always an array of objects; the unpredictability is that there are sometimes extra arrays added (eg more location details etc) which returns an out of index exception

Comment: @Nikki9696 That was exactly what I needed! Thank you! `JToken navigationPosition = o.SelectToken("$.Response..Location.NavigationPosition..Longitude");` - this is the line of code worth its length in gold

Answer (score 0):

If the response is dynamic then one option is to use dynamic deserialization

```
var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonAsString);
```

You can iterate this object and write defensive code by checking null. 
I am assuming that "NavigationPosition" will always lie under "location" and in turn under a list of "Result" under list of "View"

something like this.. (symbolic code)

```
if(dynamicObject.View != null && dynamicObject.View[0] != null && dynamicObject.View[0].Result[0] != null && dynamicObject.View[0].Result[0].Location != null  )
{
    var navigationPosition = dynamicObject.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition;
    // do something with it
}
```

It seems really cumbersome but if you have no control over json response, I think you should be able to get it right after some iterations :)

Comment: Change your if statement to use null conditional operator: if(dynamicObject.View?.FirstOrDefault()?.Result?.FirstOrDefault()?.Location != null)  Much easier to read IMO

Comment: Maybe OP wants random access without loading the whole JSON (might be a problem if you have huge JSON data). In that case this is not the right approach.

Comment: " neither can I navigate through it using key names."  -  Do not think hard coded paths would be an answer OP is looking for

Comment: I wouldn't prefer such implementation which relies on structure i have no knowledge about and which can break anytime in future. Though i feel if you have absolutely no alternative please try this http://jmespath.org/examples.html